# Difference between two perspective projection representations

Tags: opengl, mathematics, projection, perspective

When researching perspective projections on the web, I've come across two different representations. One is unrelated to OpenGL and the other is strictly associated with it.

[image: Projection 1]

[image: Projection 2]

What is the relation of these two projections? Both are called the same but the matrices are quite different. The first one seems to project unto the xy plane (z=0), the OpenGL one to the z=near plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My knowledge in matrices is not that great, but from what I understand the first one refers to **Weak-Perspective Projection**. This is meant as a "simple" way to give the illusion of 3D. The only thing it does it to make the objects with big Z values appear smaller on the screen, so it divines both the X and Y with Z.

[image]

The second matrix is the standard matrix for perspective projection, where it transforms everything in the camera's frustum (depending on its near/far plane, and left/top/right/bottom values) to a cube extending from -1 to 1 in all dimensions. Usually after this transformation, vectors are again (like in Weak-Perspective Projection) divined by Z, but that is not part of this matrix.

The results from the Weak-Perspective Projection are not ideal. Maybe this picture can help understand why:

[image]

More information on both matrices on [Wikipedia - 3D projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection)